# Apache Cordova - Media Plugin play/stop button toggle

Tags: android, apache, cordova, audio, media

I am creating a app for android using cordova plugin media. How creating a button to switch the play/stop using the function below?

```js
function playAudio(src) { my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError); my_media.play();}
function pauseAudio() { if (my_media) { my_media.pause();}}
function stopAudio() { if (my_media) { my_media.stop();}}
function onSuccess() { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");}
function onError(error) { alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');}
```

Comment: you mean you want to design button for play pause ?

Comment: Yes. the problem I have to use the function variables to work. when you click it touches the audio and click again it for audio.